# How to make video clips suitable for iPod Classic 160G under Xenial?

Tags: 16.04, codecs, ipod, video-conversion, format-conversion

I am able to sync my *music* collection with iPod Classic 160G under Xenial Xerus using GTKPod. But I would also like to place *music videos* on the same device.

Using Xenial Xerus what conversion software and what *tested* video settings will accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can best be done with FFmpeg:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56
```

and then encoding to H.264 and mp3 (the Xenial FFmpeg does not have access to the best AAC encoder `libfdk_aac` unfortunately):

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" \
       -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryslow \
       -profile:v baseline -level 3 -refs 6 \
       -vf "scale=640:-1,pad=iw:480:0:(oh-ih)/2,format=yuv420p" \
       -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 256k \
       output.mp4
```

This produces a nice video and audio playback on my iPod classic :)

A few thoughts on this technique:

1. If the audio is already AAC simply use `-c:a copy` rather than change to mp3
2. If you have compiled your own FFmpeg and have access to `libfdkaac` use something like `-c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k` for the audio

**References:**

- [Stack Overflow - Encode video for ipod classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260944/encode-video-for-ipod-classic)
- [FFmpeg Trac - Encoding MP3](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3)
- [FFmpeg Trac Encoding AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC)